# Multinomial Logistic Regresson what are the order of the coeff

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

For example if I have  4 classes (0, 1, 2, 3). If I perform L = lr.coef_ I'll have a list of coeff. They are ranked in which order ? L[0] is for 0, ..., L[3] is for 3 ? or the order is backward or even random ?

Answer (score 1):

Here L[0] will be of class 0.
the order will also be like that